# React upon entering a keyword in the message body of Create New Mail window

Tags: vba, outlook

I want, when I compose a new email, if I enter a certain keyword (e.g "#servicedesk"), there would be a pop-up that would ask me to cc the email to a specific address (servicedesk@123corp.com).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is easier to get help if you can have a go at solving the problem, then come back with specific problems relating to your code. Here is an MSDN tutorial on [creating an Outlook add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx), which should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a unique keyword, a non-VBA solution is simpler.

Create a rule.

- Apply rule on messages I send.
- with specific words in the body
- Cc the message to people or public group

If the keyword is not unique then:

Application_Itemsend example http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/macro-to-warn-before-sending-a-message-with-a-blank-subject/

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim strSubject As String
    strSubject = Item.Subject
    If Len(Trim(strSubject)) = 0 Then
        Prompt$ = "Subject is Empty. Are you sure you want to send the Mail?"
        If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check for Subject") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Use InStr to parse Item.Body. http://www.slipstick.com/developer/parsing-text-fields-in-outlook/

Then MsgBox to confirm Item.cc = "servicedesk@123corp.com"